# How to set maxTimeMS on Spring Data MongoDb Repository methods

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Spring Data MongoDB Repository provides a lot of useful ways to generate queries, e.g. derived queries, and CRUD operations. For example:

```
public interface UserMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID> {
    List<User> findByUserName(String userName);
...
```

as well as the `findById`, e.g. `userMongoRepository.findById(uuid);`

Is there a way to set additional parameters either globally or as parameters to these Spring Data methods to set the MongoDB $maxTimeMS parameter. Otherwise I will need to rewrite all these derived queries to use the `Query` class, instantiate a new `Query` object and set the `.maxTimeMsec()` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I found it's possible to add the appropriate timeout via the `@Meta` annotation:

```
public interface UserMongoRepository extends MongoRepository<User, UUID> {

    @Meta(maxExecutionTimeMs = 2000, cursorBatchSize = -1)
    Optional<User> findByUserId(UUID userId);
...
```

Note how I also set the `cursorBatchSize` to -1 so that it mimics the `findById` method of `SimpleMongoRepository`; i.e. in the debug output for the find command it will show values such as: `"limit": 1, "singleBatch": true` otherwise the limit is set to 2 and singleBatch was not set. This was in Spring Data MongoDB 3.1.9.

Answer (score -1):

After some research, I found this that I think will work for your situation:
I didn't have a test situation please try it.

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

@Bean
public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer mongoClientSettings() {
    return custom -> custom.applyToSocketSettings(builder ->
                    // this section
                    builder.connectTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                   // until here
            .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                    builder.maxSize(10)
                            .minSize(1)
                            .maxConnectionIdleTime(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .maxWaitTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .applyToClusterSettings(builder ->
                    builder.serverSelectionTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
            .applicationName("applicationName");
    }
}
```